# Не всегда отрабатывает setOnClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, случайные-числа, setonclicklistener

Логика такая - есть три ImageButton, есть функция, которая возвращает значение от 1 до 100. Когда пользователь нажимает на первую ImageButton в зависимости от значения  возвращаемого числа, вторая или третья ImageButton меняет свой background. Проблема в том, что из 10 реализаций, код может не сработать(то есть ничего не происходит ни на экране ни в логах) 1 раз или 5 раз подряд, а может и все 10 раз сработать как надо. В чем может быть ошибка? Есть подозрение, что что-то не так с рандомом.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        first_door_img.setOnClickListener {
            firstDoorSelected()
        }
}

private fun firstDoorSelected() {
        first_door_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_primary_door)

        when {
            randomDoorOpen() in 1..50 -> {
                second_door_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goat_door)
                Log.d(TAG, "firstDoorSelected: " + randomDoorOpen().toString())
                Log.d(TAG, "=====================================")

            }
            randomDoorOpen() in 51..100 -> {
                third_door_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goat_door)
                Log.d(TAG, "firstDoorSelected: " + randomDoorOpen().toString())
                Log.d(TAG, "=====================================")
            }
        }
    }

private fun randomDoorOpen(): Int {

        return (1..100).random()
    }
```

// метод сброса

```
private fun restartGame() {
        startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
    }
```

Comment: не понятно, после нескольких нажатий 1, 2, 3 дверь станут R.drawable.selected_primary_door, R.drawable.goat_door, R.drawable.goat_door и что должно происходить?

Comment: @АрменМхитарян, ну так сбрасывай состояние кнопок перед выполнением when. У тебя 2 и 3 кнопки установили изображение, за несколько нажатий, а потом они не меняют свое состояние, так как банально нету кода которое бы меняло их

Comment: Кажется мне, что засада с вызовами `randomDoorOpen()` из `when`. Если первый раз будет 51, а второй 49, то ничего не произойдет.

Comment: @danilshik состояние кнопок у меня сбрасывает по кнопке(пересозданием активити просто для пробы) и дело не в этом. Метод сброса добавил в код

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вы хотели сделать, что-то вроде этого.

```
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            first_door_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_primary_door)
            first_door_img.setOnClickListener {

                firstDoorSelected()
            }
    }

    private fun firstDoorSelected() {
            second_door_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_primary_door)
            third_door_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_primary_door)
            when {
                randomDoorOpen() in 1..50 -> {
                    second_door_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goat_door)
                    Log.d(TAG, "firstDoorSelected: " + randomDoorOpen().toString())
                    Log.d(TAG, "=====================================")

                }
                randomDoorOpen() in 51..100 -> {
                    third_door_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goat_door)
                    Log.d(TAG, "firstDoorSelected: " + randomDoorOpen().toString())
                    Log.d(TAG, "=====================================")
                }
            }
        }

    private fun randomDoorOpen(): Int {

            return (1..100).random()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильный на мой взгляд код в дополнение к комментарию к вопросу.

```
val randomDoor = randomDoorOpen()
when {
            randomDoor in 1..50 -> {
                second_door_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goat_door)
                Log.d(TAG, "firstDoorSelected: " + randomDoorOpen().toString())
                Log.d(TAG, "=====================================")

            }
            randomDoor in 51..100 -> {
                third_door_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goat_door)
                Log.d(TAG, "firstDoorSelected: " + randomDoorOpen().toString())
                Log.d(TAG, "=====================================")
            }
        }
```